# how to save string value to the tag group?

Tags: tags, dm-script

How to save the string and number value to the tag group? Do I need to create a item under user tags or put it under global tag? if there are some code example, that will help me to understand it quickly. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tagGroups` are a objects.  You can create them in your script and use them as follows:

```
TagGroup myTags = NewTagGroup()
string str = "Hello"
number num = 123
myTags.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Sub-branch:SubSub-Branch:My String", str )
myTags.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber( "My value", num )
myTags.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( "My Tags", 0 )
```

However, as with creating any other objects in a script (images, strings etc.), they are removed from memory once the script has finished.
To store info for longer than script-lifetime, you need to store the tags to any TagGroup object that *persists* in memory.

DigitalMicrograph preferences are such a TagGroup. This TagGroup stays in memory as long as DigitalMicrograph is running and is saved to the preferences on shut-down. It is the taggroup where all settings on other important things are stored, so be careful not to destroy existing tags!

Instead of creating a new TagGroup you get this existing tagGorup and modify it like in:

```
TagGroup persistentTags = GetPersistentTagGroup()
string str = "Hello"
number num = 123
persistentTags.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "My Tags:Sub-branch:SubSub-Branch:My String", str )
persistentTags.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber( "My Tags:My value", num )
```

You can also use images to store tags. Each image has an associated TagGroup. So, as long as the image is in memory, so will be the tags. Example:

```
image testImg := realImage( "Just a test", 4, 100, 100 )
testImg.ShowImage()
TagGroup imgTags = testImg.ImageGetTagGroup()
string str = "Hello"
number num = 123
imgTags.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "My Tags:Sub-branch:SubSub-Branch:My String", str )
imgTags.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber( "My Tags:My value", num )
```

Finally, if you create your own tagsGroup object like in the first example, you can save it to disc as well (.gtg file).:

```
TagGroup myTags = NewTagGroup()
string folder = "C:\\Temp\\"
string str = "Hello"
number num = 123
myTags.TagGroupSetTagAsString( "Sub-branch:SubSub-Branch:My String", str )
myTags.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber( "My value", num )

if( !DoesDirectoryExist(folder) )
    CreateDirectory(folder)

myTags.TagGroupSaveToFile( folder + "myTagFile.gtg" )
```

and then load it later like:

```
TagGroup myTags = NewTagGroup()
string Path = "C:\\Temp\\myTagFile.gtg"
if ( myTags.TagGroupLoadFromFile(path) )
    myTags.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow( path, 1 )
```